# Using poetry to install from a private repository with a token

Tags: python, pip, package, software-design, python-poetry

I have published a package on packagecloud with a token. To install this package, this URL will be used:

- https://{**some-token**}:@packagecloud.io/{some-domain}.

How do I configure poetry to download from this URL on top of the normal pypi url?

One solution that I have tried is to set the pyproject.toml manually like this:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal-package"
url = "https://{**some-token**}:@packagecloud.io/{some-domain}"
priority = "supplemental"
```

This works but is a bad practice since I am exposing the token in the .toml file. Ideally I want to use a bash script that will do the following:

- read the token from .env file
- instruct poetry to look from the url

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you try to provide credentials via ENV variables like described here? https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#http-basicnameusernamepassword

Example:
`POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_INTERNAL_PACKAGE_USERNAME={some-token} POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_INTERNAL_PACKAGE_PASSWORD="" poetry install`

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested it locally and it looks like you can securely setup the authentication in a number of different ways.

#### 1. Using POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_* environment variables

The idea is to pass the authorization credentials via environment variables. Poetry picks up credentials from the following variables:

- `POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_{SOURCE_NAME}_USERNAME` - for user name, in your case it should be the token you have.
- `POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_{SOURCE_NAME}_PASSWORD` - the password, in your case you can omit this variable, since you're using token based authentication.

Here is an example of command you can use in order to provide the token:

```
POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_INTERNAL_PACKAGE_USERNAME="{**some-token**}" poetry install
```

---

If you want to avoid adding token variable each time you may choose to append your shell rc file, e.g `.zshrc`, `.bashrc` with the following:

```
export POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_INTERNAL_PACKAGE_USERNAME="{**some-token**}"
```

This way next time you open a terminal the token will be automatically fulfilled for you.

#### 2. Set the token to the config

Poetry also allows engineers to save the token in the config (`~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/auth.toml` for Mac OS).

In order to do that you just need to simply execute the following command:

```
poetry config -- http-basic.internal-package "{**some-token**}" ""
```

Note: The last argument value is `""` for empty password.

I hope this helps you. Let me know if it works for you or you need any clarifications.